# Why is the kube-rbac-proxy process on the Kubernetes node reading a lot of disk content?

Tags: kubernetes

Viewing the monitoring data through grafana revealed that the Kubernetes node had been experiencing a large number of data reads from its disk.

[grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Dma.png)

Then I looked at the information about the processes on the Kubernetes node reading and writing to disk and found that the kube-rbac-proxy process would frequently read a lot of content from disk.

[iotop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LDtQ.png)

kube-rbac-proxy simply implements role-based access control (RBAC) and other access control mechanisms.

Why does the kube-rbac-proxy process experience a lot of reads from disk? I don't understand.

I would like to know why kube-rbac-proxy reads a lot of disks frequently. What is happening to it? Why does it do this? How to change it?

Answer (score -1):

The **kube-rbac-proxy** process is responsible for handling requests related to role-based access control (RBAC) and other access control mechanisms in a Kubernetes cluster. When a request comes in, kube-rbac-proxy needs to verify whether the request is authorized based on the RBAC rules that are defined in the cluster's configuration.

The **reason** why kube-rbac-proxy is reading a lot of data from disk is that it needs to access the configuration files that contain the RBAC rules. These files are typically stored on disk, and kube-rbac-proxy needs to read them in order to determine whether a particular request is authorized.

The frequency of disk reads by kube-rbac-proxy may increase if there are a large number of RBAC rules defined in the configuration, or if there are a large number of requests being made to the cluster.

To reduce the disk reads by kube-rbac-proxy, you can consider the following options:

1. **Optimize the RBAC rules**: Review the existing RBAC rules and remove any unnecessary or redundant rules. This can help reduce the number of rules that kube-rbac-proxy needs to process, and therefore reduce the disk reads.
2. **Increase the memory available to the kube-rbac-proxy process**: If the process has more memory available, it may be able to cache the configuration files in memory, which would reduce the frequency of disk reads.
3. **Move the RBAC configuration to a faster storage**: If possible, move the configuration files to a faster storage device such as an SSD, which can reduce the time it takes for kube-rbac-proxy to read the files.
4. **Consider using a different RBAC implementation:** Depending on your use case, you may be able to use a different RBAC implementation that is more efficient than kube-rbac-proxy. For example, Open Policy Agent (OPA) is a popular alternative that can be used with Kubernetes.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
Now that I understand how kube-rbac-proxy works, but I only have grafana, prometheus, node-exporter, and Alertmanager services using kube-rbac-proxy, it shouldn't be reading that much disk, should it? 40MB/s is a bit too much. And I don't have a lot of rbac specs, like I said, only grafana, prometheus, node-exporter, and Alertmanage use it, so where does the configuration file for the RBAC spec live on disk?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: If you only have a few services using kube-rbac-proxy, then it is possible that something else is causing the high disk usage. You may want to investigate other processes running on the system to identify the root cause of the disk usage.

Comment: Regarding the configuration file for the RBAC spec, the RBAC configuration is stored in the Kubernetes API server, not on disk. The kube-rbac-proxy reads the RBAC configuration from the API server and enforces it for the services that use it. So, there is no specific file on disk that you can modify to change the RBAC configuration. Instead, you will need to modify the RBAC configuration through Kubernetes API server by using tools such as kubectl.

Comment: I looked at the io usage of the process via the iotop command and saw that the kube-rbac-proxy process was showing a large number of io reads of 40MB/s.

Comment: After I resized the memory of the kube-rbac-proxy container, its io went down. It looks like he's back to normal. But I'm not sure how it works. I don't think kube-rbac-proxy should have a lot of disk io reads, it should only have http calls to the kube-apiserver service. So I'm not sure what the root problem is for the kube-rbac-proxy process to be doing a lot of io reads at 40MB/s.